# Does anybody knows How to get a table's hdfs directory with select statement in hive environment

Tags: hive, hdfs

I used use a select statement like 'select T** from xxx' to get a table's hdfs directory location in hive. But now  I  forgot the statement. Does anyone know it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [DESCRIBE formatted](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DescribePartition).

*The desired location*:

`Location:               file:/tmp/warehouse/part_table/d=abc`

**DEMO**

```
hive> DESCRIBE formatted part_table partition (d='abc');
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment            

i                       int                                        

# Partition Information         
# col_name              data_type               comment            

d                       string                                     

# Detailed Partition Information                
Partition Value:        [abc]                   
Database:               default                 
Table:                  part_table              
CreateTime:             Wed Mar 30 16:57:14 PDT 2016    
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                 
Protect Mode:           None                    
####### HERE IS THE LOCATION YOU WANT ########
Location:               file:/tmp/warehouse/part_table/d=abc 
Partition Parameters:           
    COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   true               
    numFiles                1                  
    numRows                 1                  
    rawDataSize             1                  
    totalSize               2                  
    transient_lastDdlTime   1459382234         

# Storage Information           
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe      
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat        
OutputFormat:                org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat      
Compressed:             No                      
Num Buckets:            -1                      
Bucket Columns:         []                      
Sort Columns:           []                      
Storage Desc Params:            
    serialization.format    1                  
Time taken: 0.334 seconds, Fetched: 35 row(s)
```